# If I must choose between 32- and 64-bit versions of some software, which should I choose? If plug-ins are available, does this make a difference?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, 32-vs-64-bit

I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 on a machine with 8 GB of memory.

Sometimes I download some software, and wonder whether to get the 32-bit (x86) or the 64-bit (x64) version.

Please assume that I won't be editing any multi-gigabyte files.

Some software developers recommend 64-bit right from the start. For example, if you visit the [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) homepage using 64-bit Windows, the "Download" button will give you the 64-bit version. This is because the developers have found that this version is [faster, more stable, and more secure](https://blog.chromium.org/2014/08/64-bits-of-awesome-64-bit-windows_26.html). Of course, in such cases, I would choose the 64-bit version.

But other software developers leave the matter up to you. They might offer you a "Download 32-bit version" link and a "Download 64-bit version" link, and you must decide which link to click.

## Part A

A) If I'm forced to make a choice, should I choose the 32-bit or the 64-bit version?

## Part B

B) If there are plug-ins or extensions available for the software, should this affect my decision?

## Important note

If you can't answer both part A and part B in one single post, please either:

- Post a comment instead of an answer.
- Or attach your answer to another question, such as [apoorv020's related question](//superuser.com/questions/271173/how-important-is-having-64-bit-programs-on-64-bit-os).

Comment: I looked around a bit. It's true that a somewhat-similar question — [apoorv020's related question](//superuser.com/questions/271173/how-important-is-having-64-bit-programs-on-64-bit-os) — was asked six years ago. But that question is old, and its answers are old, and the asker didn't really discuss plug-ins.

Comment: It'll depend on the specific software.  In the case of MS Office, MS recommends the 32-bit version unless you need to create truly humongous spreadsheets or in a few other special cases that might require huge amounts of RAM.  But some third party software (add-ins and such) doesn't work with 64-bit Office, so if you depend on add-ins, it'd be wise to check with their developer first to see if they have a 64-bit compatible version (and whether it'll cost extra).

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't concerned about memory issues, then the only considerations are practical ones. It really depends on the program, and how long the developers have been using 64 bit.

Programs that have been in existence for over 10 years were probably initially developed in 32 bit. At some point, the developers may have switched over to 64 bit. More recent programs may exist only as one or the other.

The following categories could exist:

**Older software with development focus switch to 64bit several years ago (Vista-early WIn 7 era)**

- Likely all useful plugins will have been migrated to 64 bit
- Likely 64bit release is stable, feature complete, and still being developed
- 32bit version may not receive as much development time any more
- Example [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) (switched to 64 bit years ago, plugins available for 64 bit)
- Recommend using the 64 bit version

**Older software with recent development focus switch to 64bit (Win 8-10 era) - with plugins**

- Likely most useful plugins were developed for the 32 bit version
- You'll need to check whether useful plugins work/have been ported to the 64bit version
- 64bit version may not yet be feature complete or stable if switch was very recent
- Example [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7-released.html) (works fine but not all plugins ported)
- Recommend using the 32 bit version, but tracking 64 bit progress with an intention to switch over in 2-3 releases time

**Older software with recent development focus switch to 64bit (Win 8-10 era) - without plugins**

- 64 bit version may not yet be feature complete or stable if switch was very recent
- Example [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) (recent 64 bit, works fine)
- Recommend 64 bit unless it appears to be unfinished or unstable, as future development is likely to focus on 64 bit

**Program only recently developed, available in both 32 and 64 bit**

- Likely to have same features in each version unless otherwise noted.
- Example [supply your own example here](http://example.com)
- Recommend using 64 bit as future development is likely to focus on 64 bit

Comment: What if I'm not sure how recently the development focus switched to 64-bit?

Comment: Check for user forums devoted to the software, and whether there is discussion about the 64 bit version. If it is new and there are problems with it, forums will include such topics. Check plug in download pages to see whether the plugins you need are in 64bit. If neither of those give you any red flags, use the 64 bit version to future proof your install (as updates will likely eventually stop for the 32 bit version),

Answer (score 0):

Usually the higher-bit software will operate more quickly.  (So in the context of your question, this is referring to 64-bit.  However, I've seen the same thing discussed with 16-bit software verses 32-bit software, so I'm generalizing my answer.)

This is based on some assumptions.  The higher-bit software may require more memory, which may slow things down.  However, the higher-bit software may be designed in a way that the higher-bit CPU is more optimized, which will hopefully be prone to provide improvements that offset the costs of using larger amounts of memory.

However, whether this is actually true or not can vary with different pieces of software.  So, your results may vary.

One possible advantage to the lower-bit software is that sometimes software may not be quite as compatible when using multiple bit amounts.  So, if you use a higher-bit program, that might or might not work very well with plug-ins that are designed for the lower-bit version of the program.  How much this is an issue will vary between different programs; for some programs this won't be an issue at all.

The safe thing to do is to read documentation.  If you can't (due to not finding documentation, or not having time) or won't (because you're simply not too worried about risking potential problems), then go for the higher-bit version in hopes that it provides you a better experience (namely, more speed).  If you encounter troubles, you may want to try the lower-bit version as a troubleshooting step.

Comment: When I uninstall the 64-bit version in preparation for trying the 32-bit version as a troubleshooting step, might this automatically delete any of my settings or preferences?

Comment: Might.  That depends on what software you're using.  Some software will let the 32-bit versions and 64-bit versions both be installed, and share settings.  Some won't.  Some software will delete settings when it is uninstalled; and other software won't.  Your question was general, which is why the answers you're getting aren't very specific.  If you want more specific answers, ask a new question that mentions specific software.

Comment: Nah. I asked a general question on purpose. :)

Comment: "keep in mind that, if you uninstall the higher-bit version, you might lose some of your data and/or settings." -- This text came from a proposed edit.  I am adding it as a comment so as to not lengthen the answer.  (Yes, I agree, there are cases where uninstalling software may cause some data loss.)

Comment: The answer is already long enough that a one-sentence warning about data loss won't make a big difference. The warning should probably even be in bold, so that more people will notice it.